# Bearing(revision)

Tags: calculus

Three points X,Y and Z lying in the same horizontal plane are such that the bearing of X and Y from Z are 300 and 280 and /YZ/=13m  respectively , if the bearing of Y From X is 220 degrees . Find the bearing of Z from Y?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

We measure bearings clockwise from the dotted lines. So $\angle MZX=360^o-300^o=60^o$. Similarly, $\angle NZY=360^o-280^o=80^o$, so $\angle XZY=20^o$.

$MX,NZ$ are parallel, so $\angle MXZ=120^o$. $\angle MXY=140^o$, so $\angle ZXY=100^o$. The angles in triangle $XYZ$ sum to $180^o$, so $\angle XYZ=60^o$.

$\angle MXY=140^o$, so $\angle LYX=40^o$. Hence $\angle LYZ=100^o$. So the bearing of $Z$ from $Y$ is $100^o$.

Comment: Can u explain further

Comment: What would you like me to explain further?

Comment: How you got the 120 degrees on the bearing diagram and in the solving

Comment: Because MX and NZ are parallel and $\angle NZX=60^o$.

Comment: Explain how <MXY =140

Comment: The bearing of $Y$ from $X$ is $220^o$, so the clockwise angle $MXY=220^o$, hence the anticlockwise angle is $140^o$.